# Refreshing multiple ODBC connections via background query

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-midrange

I am using a set of scripts that pull a lot of different data from iSeries via ODBC.

`ActiveWorksheets.RefreshAll` does not work as it doesn't leave enough time to run the background queries

I've tried the below,but to no avail

```
Dim qry As Connections
'Set qry =

For Each qry In ActiveWorksheets.Connections
    qry.BackgroundQuery = False
    qry.RefreshAll
    DoEvents
Next qry
```

This gives me the expected `Error 424` Object expected.
I don't expect to use `Set qry =` here, as I need to run through 30 different connections

Let's just call them connection1, connection2 etc for now, as their names are all over the place

Is the simplest option to stop the background query, refresh, activate background query - before the data import, or is there a better way?

I've looked all over SO - but can't find info on multiple ODBC connections

**EDIT:**

```
Dim qry As WorkbookConnection

For Each qry In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    qry.Refresh
    DoEvents
Next qry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work this out. So all who may need this in the future can see:

```
Dim qry As WorkbookConnection

For Each qry In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    qry.ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    qry.Refresh
    qry.ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = True
Next qry
```

Although it doesn't look like `BackgroundQuery = True/False` doesn't look like it's vital here. Turning it off means when you qry.Refresh, it pulls the data *and* refreshes it.

Also using `For Each qry` means that rather than writing out out 20 times, I can just look every connection and turn them off, refresh, and turn them back on

Answer (score 0):

I believe your

```
Dim qry As Connections
```

should read

```
Dim qry As WorkbookConnection
```

The [ActiveWorksheets.Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.connections).Item property returns an object of type [WorkbookConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection). If you are trying to refresh the connections one at a time as it seems from your `For Each` statement, that object represents a single connection with methods like `Refresh` rather than the collection of all connections.

Comment: I don't need to refresh them one at a time - I just thought it might be the only way to allow the `background query` to run. I've edited my data to show this change - when I run my script I'm still not getting the right data, but when I refreshAll via excel, it works fine